# Executing a php script using cronjob in centos

Tags: php, cron, call

I want to call a php script every minute using cron
i added the the below code in my crontab file

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php
```

but it dint give me the desired output.
Am i missing something?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What output are you getting? Does `test.php` include an other php files?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check what happens when this php file runs by following

1. just use `*` instead of `*/1`
2. `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php >> /var/www/html/test.txt`

test.txt file will contain any error or anything else which cause your test.php to not working. and if it's not loading anything in test.txt, please double check your path to your file.

1. alternatively try running `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php` from your centos console to check whether everything ok with path to your 'php' and 'test.php' file.